# Swift - Why is Class Instance Appended to Array Deinitialized?

Tags: arrays, swift, memory, reference

I'm having memory problems with the Swift code below.

In GameScene's sceneDidLoad(), I add a GKEntity to the array "entities," but in GameScene's update(), the array "entities" is empty. Shouldn't the reference to "entity" be preserved in "entities"? Why is "entity" being deinitialized at the end of sceneDidLoad()?

```
import GameplayKit

class GraphicsComponent: GKComponent {
  override func update(deltaTime: TimeInterval) {
    // ...
  }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
  
  var entities = [GKEntity]()
  
  override func sceneDidLoad() {
    let entity = GKEntity()
    entity.addComponent(GraphicsComponent())
    entities.append(entity)
  }

  override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    
    // ...

    for entity in entities {
      entity.update(deltaTime: dt)
    }
  }
}
```

I was expecting the "entity" instance to be preserved because a reference to it was added to the "entities" array. If that reference remained, then why was the instance destroyed?

EDIT:

I found that if I move the code in `sceneDidLoad()` to `didMove()`, everything works as expected. I still didn't know why, so I looked around in the boilerplate that Xcode puts in `GameViewController` and found where `sceneDidLoad()` and `didMove()` are each called. I found that if I add an `entity` to the `scene.entities` array in `sceneDidLoad()`, the `scene.entities` array will be empty when the code steps into the if statement that begins with `if let scene = GKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")`. Is the `if let` creating a temporary `GKScene`?

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   
    // This "if let" will call sceneDidLoad(), which appends a new entity to scene.entities.
    if let scene = GKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
      // scene.entities.count = 0
      
      if let sceneNode = scene.rootNode as! GameScene? {
        
        sceneNode.entities = scene.entities
        sceneNode.graphs = scene.graphs
        
        sceneNode.scaleMode = .aspectFill
      
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
          view.presentScene(sceneNode) // This calls didMove()
          view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
          view.showsFPS = true
          view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `update` is called after `sceneDidLoad`?

Comment: Yes, `sceneDidLoad` is always called first